# IP Load Balancing - Number of requests limit

Tags: load-balancing, vps, ovh

I want to configure IP Load Balancing service for our VPS. I have got the documentation at http://docs.ovh.ca/en/products-iplb.html#presentation where I can integrate it.

I want to limit the number of requests on each server (S1, S2). How can I achieve this?

Suppose, I want S1 should handle all requests if requests sent to load balancer are less than 3500 per minute.

If requests are greater than 3500 (per minute), then load balancer should forward all extra requests to S2.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Just had a look and I believe you won't be able to achieve what you are looking for with the available load balancing algorithm.

If you look at the available ones, you can see five ldb algorithm. I would say from my experience with load balancers (not from OVH) that they should do the following:

First: probably the first real server to reply (with health monitor) will get the query

leastcon:  this distributes connections to the server that is currently managing the fewest open connections at the time the new connection request is received.

roundrobin: next connection is given to the next real server in line

source: not sure about this one but I believe you load-balance per src ip. Eg if request is coming from 143.32.Y.Z, send it to server A etc.

uri: I believe it load balances by URI. Typical if you are hosting different webservers.

I would advise to check with OVH what you can do. Typically in those scenario with an F5 load balancer for example, you can configure a simple script for this. Or groups, if the first group fail, we sent the traffic to the second one.
Now a ratio (also called weighted) ldb algo can do the job, not exactly what you want indeed.

Cheers